# Terminal filesystem location

Tags: debian, gnome

I'm using gnome 3 on debian. I want to create a launcher on the desktop for terminal. Where is terminal in the file system?

I tried "which terminal" but it doesn't output anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its gnome-terminal and the loaction should be /usr/bin/gnome-terminal